# Formset ignores field's initial value

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

Here's a form, `MyForm` which has a field `my_field` with an initial value of 10.

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.IntegerField(
        initial=10,
        widget=forms.NumberInput(
            {
                'class': f'form-control',
            }
        ),
        label='',
    )
```

whenever a formset is generated, it ignores the initial value, otherwise it works perfectly fine:

`views.py`

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render

from myapp.forms import MyForm


def index(request):
    factory = formset_factory(MyForm)
    match request.method:
        case 'POST':
            formset = factory(request.POST)
            if formset.is_valid():
                print(formset.cleaned_data)
        case _:
            formset = factory()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'formset': formset})
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what happens when I just submit the form without modifying the field value. I'm expecting to see a value of 10 in the cleaned form which contains nothing instead.

```
[{}]
[29/Mar/2023 01:07:34] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 867
```

Despite the presence of the value in `request.POST`

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['nH5YM6syXup35jiI0O0XKgq3DsWVr4UuMb6ZvRm62gl5F3vtCYZAIiK9v0WWChZN'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['1'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'form-0-my_field': ['10']}>
```

Then I set the value to 5, it works fine:

```
[{'my_field': 5}]
[29/Mar/2023 01:07:47] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 866
```

One workaround I'm currently using is to do this or an equivalent dedicated function that manually overrides a given field's `has_changed` method:

```
my_field.has_changed = lambda *args: True
```

which always indicates the field was changed and triggers a form cleaning call.

Comment: Wait is the printout of this: `print(formset.cleaned_data)`?  A formset doesn't have cleaned_data, it's the individual forms in the formset that do, I'm guessing that if there's only one, it prints it.  Try `for form in formset: print(form.cleaned_data)`

Comment: I included what's contained in `formset.cleaned_data` in both cases, the initial and the entered value respectively. It's a list of form fields and their values per each form in the formset. I just edited the question and included a workaround I'm currently using until finding a better solution if one exists.